# sed print text between PATTERN1 and PATTERN2 OR PATTERN3

Tags: sed, pattern-matching

Can sed print text between PATTERN1 and PATTERN2 OR PATTERN3?  For instance, for both samples below I want the output shown:

Sample 1

```
Not lemur
Lemur
  Ring-Tailed
  Mouse
  Catta
Fusa
  Bad
```

Sample 2

```
Not lemur
Lemur
  Ring-Tailed
  Mouse
  Catta
```

Desired output:

```
Lemur
  Ring-Tailed
  Mouse
  Catta
```

My sed command so far is `sed -n '/^Lemur/,$p'`, but that also prints the "Fusa\n  Bad", which I don't want.  Does sed have an "OR" feature, like `'/^Lemur/,($|^[^\s])p'` with the intent to match from Lemur to the end of the input or a line that does not start with whitespace.  Also, I want to only print the lines after the first pattern (Lemur) that start with whitespace (i.e. I do not want to print "Fusa" in the first sample).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sed is the best tool for doing `s/old/new/` on individual strings. For anything more complicated than that, just use awk.

```
$ awk '/^\S/{f=/^Lemur/} f' file1
Lemur
  Ring-Tailed
  Mouse
  Catta

$ awk '/^\S/{f=/^Lemur/} f' file2
Lemur
  Ring-Tailed
  Mouse
  Catta
```

If you don't have GNU awk for `\S` then just use `[^[:space:]]` instead.

Comment: Very interesting solution.  It took a minute to wrap my mind around it, but I think I get it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed ':a;/^Lemur/{:b;n;/^\S/ba;bb};d' file
```

Label the beginning of the the cycle.

If a line begins with the word `Lemur`:

- Label the beginning of a loop.
- Print current line and fetch the next into the pattern space.
- If the pattern space begins with a non space-like character, go to the beginning of the cycle and repeat.
- Otherwise go to the beginning of the loop.

All other lines delete.

---

An alternative:

```
sed -n '/^\S/{:a;x;/^Lemur/p;$q;x;h};//!H;$ba' file
```